# Can I use DDR4 PC2400T and DDR4 PC2400 memory together?

Tags: memory, ramdisk

I recently got a samsung memory 4GB PC 2400T,I am not sure if I can use both PC2400T and PC2400 together.

Comment: Have you looked at the related questions in the "Related" list (on the right)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The T suffix at the end means it meets a specific [JEDEC standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DDR4_SDRAM#JEDEC_standard_DDR4_module). A 2400T module will have the standard clock rates for a PC-2400 stick, and has a timing of 17-17-17, and a CAS latency of 14.16(ns).

The PC-2400 is just a non-specified variant. It will for sure have the same clock rates, but it may have different timing and CAS latency.

A lot of manufactures don't use a JEDEC suffix at the end. Of the sticks I've ever bought, I don't recall it ever having a suffix at the end.

Just look at the timings and CAS latency on both sticks. This information should be on the label. It could turn out that the PC-2400, actually matches PC-2400T.

Generally, you want to use the exact same RAM. In the end, you can try it out and see what happens. If it does boot and seems to be working fine, download [CPU-Z](https://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html) and check the memory tab. You'll be able to see the timings and ensure that they're working in dual channel mode.